# Will factory reset bring back my windows and solve the booting problems?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, operating-systems

So initially I had Windows 10, then I installed OpenSuse Tumbleweed for dual boot. But for some reason I am not able to boot into windows and I can't see the option of Windows in the BIOS either. Now if I factory reset my PC, will it bring back my windows?

Comment: See if the [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) can fix your boot menu.

Comment: Try Super Grub2 Disk before reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I factory reset my PC, will it bring back my windows?

No.

Windows reset can be performed only from a working Windows OS.
If you're confusing the above with firmware (BIOS or UEFI) reset, then it has no bearing either.

If your Windows 10 was preinstalled then it is in UEFI mode. Any Linux in dual-boot should be installed in the same UEFI mode. If yours wasn't than you shouldn't expect the dual-boot to work.

That said, if actually preinstalled, hence in UEFI mode, then you must have "Windows Boot Manager" as an option in UEFI settings > Boot. If however it was installed by you or any other user then bets are off, it could be anything.

Comment: Yes my Windows 10 was installed in UEFI mode. But my linux boots in Legacy mode. So is that the reason the dual boot isn't working? But if that's the case then I should get the option for windows on switching to UEFI mode in the BIOS right?

Comment: If you enabled Legacy mode to boot into Linux that is the reason you cannot boot into Windows

Comment: As above. The only way to "work" with this not-dual-boot is to change mode in UEFI to boot one or the other.